# Why does Firebase say my app both does not exist and already exists at the same time?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-admin

I'm trying hard to initialize my Firebase app in my Python project. I'm only doing this initialization in one place, but I keep getting errors about my app already existing.

In an effort to fix the problem, I changed my initialization code to try to catch the errors:

```
class Firestore(Datastore):
    _app: firebase_admin.App
    _db: firestore.client

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self._app = firebase_admin.get_app('TaskRatchet')
        except ValueError:
            is_dev = 'TR_ENV' in os.environ and os.environ['TR_ENV'] == 'development'
            base_path = f'{pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()}/../../'
            dev_cred = f'{base_path}/[file name].json'
            prod_cred = f'{base_path}/[file name].json'
            path = dev_cred if is_dev else prod_cred
            cred = credentials.Certificate(path)

            self._app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(credential=cred, name='TaskRatchet')

        self._db = firestore.client(self._app)
```

But now it says the app both exists and doesn't exist at the same time!

> function_1  | ValueError: Firebase app named "TaskRatchet" does not exist. Make sure to initialize the SDK by calling initialize_app() with your app name as the second argument.
>
> function_1  |
>
> function_1  | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> function_1  | [...]
>
> function_1  | ValueError: Firebase app named "TaskRatchet" already exists. This means you called initialize_app() more than once with the same app name as the second argument. Make sure you provide a unique name every time you call initialize_app().

How on earth am I getting errors saying the app both does not and does exist at the same time, and within the same exception chain?

And how can I gracefully ensure that only one app is created?

---

In case it helps, here is the full relevant portion of the exception chain:

> function_1  | ERROR:tr_api.main:Fatal error
>
> function_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> function_1  |   File "/usr/src/app/tr_api/datastores/firestore.py", line 16, in **init**
>
> function_1  |     self._app = firebase_admin.get_app('TaskRatchet')
>
> function_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/firebase_admin/**init**.py", line 139, in get_app
>
> function_1  |     raise ValueError(
>
> function_1  | ValueError: Firebase app named "TaskRatchet" does not exist. Make sure to initialize the SDK by calling initialize_app() with your app name as the second argument.
>
> function_1  |
>
> function_1  | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> function_1  |
>
> function_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> function_1  |   File "/usr/src/app/tr_api/main.py", line 46, in main
>
> function_1  |     datastore = factory.secure(Firestore)
>
> function_1  |   File "/usr/src/app/tr_api/factory.py", line 17, in secure
>
> function_1  |     obj = self.make(class_, **kwargs)
>
> function_1  |   File "/usr/src/app/tr_api/factory.py", line 26, in make
>
> function_1  |     return class_(**deps)
>
> function_1  |   File "/usr/src/app/tr_api/datastores/firestore.py", line 25, in **init**
>
> function_1  |     self._app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(credential=cred, name='TaskRatchet')
>
> function_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/firebase_admin/**init**.py", line 79, in initialize_app
>
> function_1  |     raise ValueError((
>
> function_1  | ValueError: Firebase app named "TaskRatchet" already exists. This means you called initialize_app() more than once with the same app name as the second argument. Make sure you provide a unique name every time you call initialize_app().

Answer (score 2):

Rewriting my init function like so seems to have solved the issue:

```
class Firestore(Datastore):
    _app: firebase_admin.App
    _db: firestore.client

    def __init__(self):
        is_dev = 'TR_ENV' in os.environ and os.environ['TR_ENV'] == 'development'
        base_path = f'{pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()}/../../'
        dev_cred = f'{base_path}/[file name].json'
        prod_cred = f'{base_path}/[file name].json'
        path = dev_cred if is_dev else prod_cred
        cred = credentials.Certificate(path)

        try:
            self._app = firebase_admin.get_app('TaskRatchet')
        except ValueError:
            self._app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(credential=cred, name='TaskRatchet')

        self._db = firestore.client(self._app)
```

I'm really unsure as to why this seems to have solved the issue.